# How to solve $ \prod \limits_{i=1}^{99}[i]_{100} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve: $\prod \limits_{i=1}^{99}[i]_{100}=?$

Due to the fact that i is always smaller than 100, I assume I can solve this example just by multiplying the following values: $1*2*3*4*5…*98*99$ ? The problem is I have no calculator that is able to do such big numbers.

Is there a way to solve this in a more efficient way than multiplying every element?

Comment: What does the notation $[p]_q$ mean? Maybe some sort of modulo operation? I haven't seen that...

Comment: yes the q means i mod 100

Comment: You d not want to **solve** that expresion: you want to **evaluate** it.

Comment: So if you want the result to be also expressed mod 100, it is $[0]_{100}$, right?

Comment: yes the result should be expressed as mod 100

Comment: $[2]_{100} [5]_{100} [10]_{100} = [100]_{100} = [0]_{100}$

Comment: See [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woah there.  No need to multiply every element.

**Hint**:  If $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ and $x \equiv y \pmod{n}$, then $ax \equiv by \pmod{n}$.

Can you prove this?  Can you generalize it to products of arbitrary lengths?

From here, we can apply the commutative property of multiplication since $\mathbb{Z}_{100}$ is a commutative ring (Prove this).  Doing so, I encourage you to first multiply together, say, $4$ and $25$, *and then* the rest of the numbers and see what happens.

You should find that the calculation actually turns out to be far, far simpler than actually multiplying everything together.

---

Alternative way of thinking about it: evaluating a number $\pmod{100}$ is the same as finding the last $2$ digits of that number in its fully expanded base-10 representation (why?).  So, for example, $182425 \equiv 25 \pmod{100}$.  So without much effort, can you see what the last two digits of $\displaystyle \prod_{k = 1}^{99} k$ will be?

Comment: It's a commutative ring because for every x in $Z_{100}$ -(-(x))=x, x*0=0 and -(x*y)= -(x)*y=x*(-y)
25*4=100 mod 100 = 0, but do I have to apply the mod after I executed the product or for every element?

If I apply mod 100 for every multiplication in the product and result in one product beeing zero, the whole product should be zero?

Comment: Your last sentence is getting to the right idea.  A slightly different way to see why its true...You should be able to find the "hint" sentence somewhere in your textbook.  So let $a$ be $4 \cdot 25$ and  $x$ be the product of everything else.  Then computing $ax \equiv (??) \pmod{100}$, we get...

Answer (score 3):

Since $4$ and $25$ divides $99!$, it follows that $100$ must divide $99!$. Hence the entire expression is simply $0$ modulo $100$.